# c3 with crossfilter example

Tags: angularjs, crossfilter, c3.js

I have a data set of 1500 lines in csv format. I am able to build it using c3js as in this example. http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html .

I am trying to use crossfilter along with c3js. Is there a directive for this to integrate c3js with angular + crossfiter?

Fairly new to d3 so facing this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say about how to integrate c3js with angular and crossfilter, but if you really want to make use of the wonderful features of [Crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) on your data, you may want to prefer [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) which is intuitive and easy to work. `dc.js` is perfect to work with `crossfilter`.